# how to show html contents in browser using c# class library

Tags: c#, html

I want to browse html content without creating html file using c#.Net class library like below and it navigate to another page mention in action tag of form with post as method for form submitting, so it hides parameters that contains in url

```
    string html ="<html><body><form name='form1' id='form1' method='post' action='http://default.aspx'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='id1'></form>
<script> document.form1.submit(); </script></body></html>"

WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

browser.Navigate("about:blank");
if (browser.Document != null)
{
    browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);
}
browser.DocumentText = html;
```

But it wont showed anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any visible elements in your HTML.

This works (for a WebBrowser dropped on a winform):

```
    String HTML =  @"<html><body>Hello World</body></html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = HTML;
```

Comment: Hi Steve..
   I am working with c#.Net Class library. So there is no any webform/winform. 
   I want to directly open this in any default browser. Is there is another way to display this content.

Comment: @Sushant - You can create and show a windows form from your DLL.  I updated my answer.